# 4K TV limited to 30Hz. Is there way to get 60Hz by lowering resolution or something similar?

Tags: hdtv, 4k-resolution

I received a [Sceptre U435CV-UMC 4K TV](https://www.sceptre.com/TV/4K-UHD-TV/U435CV-UMC-43-4K-UHD-TV-product933category1category73.html) as a gift, but my graphics card ([MSI Radeon R9 380 Gaming 4GB VRAM](https://us.msi.com/Graphics-card/R9-380-GAMING-4G.html#hero-specification)) doesn't support HDMI 2.0 and the TV doesn't have any DisplayPort ports, so I'm not able to get anything higher than 30 Hz.

Is there any way for me to get 60 Hz out of it? I tried lowering the resolution to 1080p through Windows 10 advanced display settings to see if that helped, but it didn't.

Comment: I don't think you can make your display adapter output something it wasn't built for, but I'm no expert.

Comment: HDMI 1.x defines up to 3.96 Gbit/s of video bandwidth.  1080p at 60 Hz fits in this bandwidth, so lowering your resolution to 1080p **should** have worked.

Comment: changing resolution on a matrix pixel display like LCD, plasma or OLED is a bad idea, because the quality will be much worse, unless the native resolution is an exact multiple of the new resolution

Answer (score 1):

The monitor was still tuned to 30Hz. Once I manually set it to run at 60Hz, it behaved as expected. How to set to 60Hz:

After you change your resolution to 1080p, click "Display adapter properties" in Advanced Display Settings

[image]

Go to the Monitor tab, select the dropdown under Screen refresh rate, and select 60 Hz:

[image]

Then click Apply and you'll be good to go.